# How to save large html content

Tags: java

If there is a blog website,
I want to know whether  save  the large html content to databse directly is a better way or is there any other way to process the html content.

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: in blog website ,i want to know where the lots of articles save

Answer (score 0):

On a website such as a blog, the blog posting's title and text are stored in a database as plain texts without the html. When you view a page, the web framework fetches the text content of the page from a database and uses a template to format it to a html page.

You should find a book to get into all this. How all this works is a far too broad question for this site.